# Probability distribution for a random walk in arbitrary dimension

Tags: random-walk

I'm trying to find the probability distribution for a random walk on a lattice with lattice constant a in arbitrary dimension d. The rules for my walk is that in each step the walker has to move to an adjacent spot on the lattice along one and only one component. My logic is as follows.

My probability distribution ought to be

$$\rho^L_{\vec{r}/a, t/\tau} = \langle \delta_{\vec{R}(t), \vec{r}} \rangle.$$

Here, $\vec{r}$ is my final position vector from the starting point of the walk, t is the total time since we started the walk and $\tau$ the time per step. $\vec{R}(t)$ is a random variable consistent with the final position of the walk. $L$ simply indicates that we are on a lattice, and is merely included for consistency with my textbook. The delta-function is a d-dimensional delta function, d being the dimensionality of my lattice. Since the delta-function is normalized the right-hand side should represent the probability distribution of my random walk. Using the Fourier representation of a delta function, and the fact that a multidimensional delta-function is a product of single dimensional delta-functions, I can rewrite my probability distribution as

$$\rho^L_{\vec{r}/a, t/\tau} = \langle \prod_{i=1}^d \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{dq_i}{2 \pi} e^{iq_i(R_i(t)-r_i)/a} \rangle.$$

$R_i$ and $r_i$ represent the ith component of my random variable and the ith component of the position on my lattice whose probability I want to find respectively. I can rewrite $R_i$ as follows:

$$R_i = \sum_j^{t/\tau} \xi_{j,i}.$$

Here, my $\xi_{j,i}$ represent the change in $R_i$ on step j. Writing $M=t/\tau$ my probability distribution is therefore

$$\rho^L_{\vec{r}/a, t/\tau} = \prod_{i=1}^d \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{dq_i}{2 \pi} e^{-iq_ir_i/a} \langle \prod_{j=1}^M e^{iq_i \xi_{j,i}/a} \rangle.$$

$\xi_{j,i}/a$ can take on values of +1, 0, or -1 with probability 1/2d, (d-1)/d, and 1/2d respectively. So

$$\langle e^{iq_i \xi_{j,i}/a} \rangle  = \frac{e^{iq_i}}{2d} + \frac{d-1}{d} + \frac{e^{-iq_i}}{2d} = \frac{\cos \left( q_i \right) + d - 1}{d}$$

$$\rho^L_{\vec{r}/a, t/\tau} = \prod_{i=1}^d \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \frac{dq_i}{2 \pi} e^{-iq_ir_i/a} \left[  \frac{\cos \left( q_i \right) + d - 1}{d} \right]^M$$

Most of the probability distributions I'v seen for the d-dimensional random walk are based on combinatoric considerations. Can anyone confirm that the logic and final expression for my probability distribution are correct. Also, does anyone have any advice on how to proceed with the final integral? Thanks.

**Edit:** Computer simulations show that my model is only valid for d=1, though I don't see why. I computed the integral numerically using wolfram alpha.

Comment: Is time continuous or discreet?  What textbook are you using? Mathematically.... what is a lattice constant?  Why should what you wrote be the appropriate distribution?  What do the brackets in $\langle \delta_{R(r),r} \rangle$ mean?  This is just a thought... but maybe if you think $\mathbb{R}^d$ as $\mathbb{R}\times... \times \mathbb{R}$ then you can answer your questions since apparently you have it resolved for $d=1$.  In my notation above, I mean to emphasize that this walk is really a simultaneous walk of $d$ 1-dimensional walks.

Comment: Time is continuous, however shouldn't matter since in the final expression I have recast the equation in terms of M, the total number of steps. The lattice constant represents the spacing between adjacent points on the lattice. The <> notation denotes expected value, and since the delta function is normalized the expected value in my first equation should denote the true probability. I think the problem is in going from my second equation to my fourth equation. I didn't take into account the covariance of the $\xi_{j,i}$, and therefore my expected value algebra is wrong.